# Data of promise result cannot be used

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I've got some noob question I guess, but I can't undestand why this code not working as expected.
Problem is that I want to use result of my promise (array) to call ids that I need, but for some reason its not working as I expect. If I call `b.then((customerIds) => customerIds)` just after b, I got my array with values, but if I call it on body, its not working.

```js
const a = fetch('/orders').then(rawOrders => rawOrders.json())
let b = a.then((orders) => {
  let customersList = []
  orders.forEach(element => {
    customersList.push(element.customer)
  });
  return customersList
})

fetch('/users', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    ids: b.then((customerIds) => customerIds)
  }) // Here is the problem
}).then(rawUsers => rawUsers.json()).then(users => console.log('users', users));
```

Comment: `ids: b.then((customerIds) => customerIds)` ... since `.then` returns a promise, `ids` will be a promise ... so, inside something like `b.then(customerList => { code code code})` you can use `ids:customerlist`

Comment: still not really clear for me, i undestood that ids now a promise, but how can i use my value of customerList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the second fetch inside `b.then` callback

like:

```
const a = fetch('/orders').then(rawOrders => rawOrders.json())
let b = a.then((orders) => {
    let customersList = []
    orders.forEach(element => {
        customersList.push(element.customer)
    });
    return customersList
});
b.then(customerIds =>fetch('/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ids: customerIds
    })
})).then(rawUsers => rawUsers.json()).then(users => console.log('users', users));
```

Although, I'd usually write that whole code block like

```
fetch('/orders')
.then(rawOrders => rawOrders.json())
.then(orders => orders.map(({customer}) => customer))
.then(ids => fetch('/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ids})
}))
.then(rawUsers => rawUsers.json())
.then(users => console.log('users', users))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

One long promise chain - with a catch at the end

Or async/await

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const rawOrders = await fetch('/orders');
        const orders => await rawOrders.json();
        const ids = orders.map(({customer}) => customer);
        const rawUsers = await fetch('/users', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ids})
        });
        const users = await rawUsers.json();
        console.log('users', users);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

(the async IIFE is only needed if this code isn't inside an async function)

Comment: ok, i got the idea, thanks for helping, will learn about it more. Thanks a lot!